# Google Geocoding API suddenly returns only one result

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I am using Google Maps Geocoding Api in one of my applications in order to get addresses from a user address search term. It was working fine but now it returns only one result every time. There is also an open issue here:

[Open issue with Geocoding API](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal&groupby=&sort=&id=8831)

Do you have any idea of what is may happenning?

From what I can see, if the search is quite generic then google returns only one result.